# Jobs status: Failed. But no errors

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In the Dataflow UI the `Job status` is `Failed`. The Job Logs is empty, the Worker Logs is empty and the Job Error Reporting is empty. StackDriver is completely empty.

How to find out what went wrong?

[image]

Comment: You could start by posting something else than your words here, otherwise you will not get much help

Comment: ok I added a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the job was marked as failed, it means that Dataflow does received it. Please double check the existence of the logs by following [the troubleshooting steps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#Workflow). In addition, I recommend paying attention in the Job Graph to see where exactly the job failed and review the details of a specific step.

If the link above confirms that there are not logs, you should check that [ingestion Stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#stop-logs) was not stopped. To verify if logs are ingested in Stackdriver, you can access [Logging Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces) directly and search for Dataflow logs and the failed job id.

Finally, if steps above don't help, I strongly recommend filing a support ticked to GCP for further assistance on your specific job.

Comment: thanks, I did not find out what happend but I will use your advice the next time a job fails.